# SQL Merge Multiple Rows together Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, sql-server-2016

I have an table with the following layout

```
Row   ID      Name    Notes
1     100     A       Full Text
2     200     B       Full Text
3     300     C       Text part1
4                     Text part2
5                     Text part3
6     400     D       Full Text
```

Where sporadically the contents of the Notes cell for a row has been filled into the rows below it (e.g. row 3 has notes content in rows 4 and 5.) In other words, Row 3 was the last 'valid' row. I need to concatenate the notes content from rows 4 and 5 to row 3. How can I merge the notes content into a single row (row 3) and delete the no longer needed rows (rows 4 and 5)? So the final product will look like so

```
Row   ID      Name    Notes
1     100     A       Full Text
2     200     B       Full Text
3     300     C       Full Text
6     400     D       Full Text
```

Comment: what is your sqlserver version?

Comment: If you had some kind of identification that shows those rows are groups, then you could use String_Agg(). As of now, there is nothing that says rows with ID 3,4,5 are in the same group. What is the logic?

Comment: Why repeat `text3` 3 times, if it's going to be the same value each time?

Comment: @Fahmi see tag.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I updated the information about the table

Comment: @Larnu see updated layout

Comment: I don't see something that is worth to call as "updated". Still it is missing how you deduct that 3,4,5 are related. You kind of seem to be using that table as a text file where Row means the Row in text file? How do you know Rows 4,5 don't belong to Row 6 but 3? Gordon Linoff's reply already answer your peculiar way of using the table as a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cumulative `count()` to assign groups and then aggregate:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(row)) as row,
       min(id) as id, min(name) as name,
       string_agg(text, ' ') within group (order by row) as text
from (select t.*,
             count(id) over (order by row) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of SQL Server, you can use:

```
select min_row, id,
       stuff( (select ' ' + t.notes
               from t t2
               where t2.row >= i.min_row and
                     (t2.row < i.max_row or i.max_row is null)
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as notes
from (select id, name, min(row) as min_row, lead(min(row)) over (order by id) as max_row
      from t
      group by by id, name
     ) i;
```

Comment: I have a different environment that runs SQL Server 2016. How would I get around the lack of string_agg for 2016? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @user3277752 . . . Is there a maximum number of intermediate rows that you have?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? The original table is 100k rows.

Comment: @user3277752 . . . What is the maximum number of rows with `NULL` ids that need to be combined into one row?

Comment: At a cursory glance it seems like 60 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql server 2016, then you can try this query:

```
--you are getting NumberGroup (using window function )
with cte as
(
  select *, sum(ID)over(order by Row rows unbounded preceding)NumGr from Table
)

-- using FOR XML PATH to get one row within group (Full text in your case)
select min(Row)Row,
max(ID)ID,max(Name)Name,max(Notes_new)Notes
from
(
 select *, stuff((select ' '+ Notes from cte cte1 where cte1.NumGr=cte2.NumGr 
 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')Notes_new
 from cte cte2
)X
group by NumGr
```